# Casting in a Class Hierarchy

Tags: java

`Object aThing = new Integer(25);`

According to my text book, the expression `(Integer) aThing` casts the type of the object referenced by `aThing`(type `Object`) to type `Integer`. **The casting operation will succeed only if the object referenced by `aThing` is, in fact type `Integer`**; if not, a `ClassCastException` will be thown

I don't understand what the bolded sentence is saying. Can you briefly elaborate on that?

what is the "object referenced by `aThing`"?

Comment: @downvoter state the reason of your downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object aThing = new Integer(25);
```

Now since `aThing` reference points to an `Integer object`. So, you can cast that reference to an `Integer`. Because an `integer` reference can point to an `Integer` object.

```
Integer intRef = (Integer)aThing; // Ok, `aThing` points to an Integer object
```

But when you try to typecast that reference to a `String` reference, then you will get `ClassCastException` because, a String is not an `Integer`, and hence cannot contain a reference to an `Integer` object.

```
// Exception. A String reference cannot point to `Integer` object
String strRef = (String)aThing;
```

Comment: what is the "object referenced by `aThing`"?

Comment: @user133466 `aThing` is a reference of type `Object` as you see on `LHS` in your example. And it points to an `Integer Object`, as on `RHS`.

Answer (score 2):

If you had

```
Object aThing = "foo";
```

then `aThing` would really be a `String`.  In that case, `(Integer) aThing` would throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: what is the "object referenced by `aThing`"?

Answer (score 0):

Note that casting from a type into another is only valid if the cast notation is in part of an inheritance tree.

So `Object x  = (String)"X"` is valid as "X" is a String object `(Object)"X"` is also valid
`Object y = (Integer) 1` is valid. (Object)1 is valid.

What you can't do however is cast one type into a completely different type.

`Object x = (Integer)"X"` it isn't valid as "X" is not of type `Integer`;

Another thing to note is you this will work.

```
class A extends B implements IInterface.
class C implements IInterface
A a = new A() ;

B b = (B)a; 
IInterface c = (IInterface)a ;
```

The above is valid as `A a` is an object of type `B` and `IInterface`. 
What you can't do is

```
C c = (C) a;
```

A a isn't of type C and will throw the ClassCastException you get.

The object referenced by `aThing`  will be what the object you initialized it.

```
String s = "Hello World"
```

s holds a pointer/reference to the "Hello World" object.

```
Person person = new Person();
```

person holds a reference to the object created.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```
FooClass foo = new FooClass();
Object aThing = foo;
Integer anInt = (Integer) aThing;
```

This code would throw a `ClassCastException` because the original object, `foo` was not an `Integer` object. Now consider this code:

```
Integer int1 = new Integer(1);
Object aThing = int1;
Integer int2 = (Integer) aThing;
```

This code would work, because the original object `int1` was an `Integer`, so if it is stored as a more general type, like `Object` it can then be cast back to the original class.

Answer (score 0):

> ## I don't understand what the bolded sentence is saying. Can you briefly elaborate on that?

Java objects at runtime contain information identifying which class the object is.  When you attempt to cast an object to a different type, the JRE will first verify that you are, in fact, casting between compatible objects.  The bold sentence isn't quite correct in a general sense either; it will also allow you to cast and object to any superclass of that object, or to any interface which that object implements.

This particular part about being castable to superclasses is why you can store your `Integer` as an `Object` anyway - `Object` is implicitly a superclass of all classes.

This behavior is why you can write a correct statement like:

```
Object aThing = new Integer(25); // cast Integer to superclass (Object)
```

Remember, objects in java contain runtime information which determines the exact identity of the object.  Downcasting to an object does not remove this information, which is why java won't let you get away with something like the following:

```
Object aThing = new Integer(25); // cast Integer to superclass (Object)
String something = (String) aThing; // cast Integer (stored as object) to String
```

That statement will compile, but you'll get a `ClassCastException` at runtime since `Integer` is not compatible with `String`.

> ## What is "the object referenced by `aThing`"?

After the line:

```
Object aThing = new Integer(25); // cast Integer to superclass (Object)
```

`aThing` is a reference to an `Integer` storing the value 25.  Remember again that object class identity is maintained at runtime, and is not lost when casting.

Comment: your final statement "object class identity is maintained at runtime, and is not lost when casting." means that `aThing` will remain as `Object`, is that the meaning of your final statement?

Comment: Nope, it means precisely the opposite.  `aThing` is a reference to something which knows it's an `Integer`.  You can cast `Integer` to `Object` because `Integer` is a subclass of `Object`, but the instance does not forget that it's an `Integer`, and won't let you later cast it to a `String` because `Integer` is not compatible with `String`.

Comment: It's an `Integer`, stored in a reference to an `Object`.